# In Python, how do I reference an argument passed from "subprocess.run" in the subprocess being run?

Tags: python-3.x, variables, subprocess, parameter-passing

In my main function, I want to pass a variable to a subprocess, have the subprocess do something with the variable, and return control to the main process.

I've read several posts about passing variables (arguments) to subprocess, but I can't find anything on accessing the variable in the subprocess.

Here's an example of what I am trying to do.

a.py

```
import subprocess

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Code to generate fn_new

    fn_new = r"path\to\file.ext"    # I want to pass this variable to b.py

    subprocess.run(["python", "b.py", fn_new])    # I read that this is how to pass the var to the subprocess

    # Additional code that depends on fn_new
```

b.py

```
print(fn_new)

# NOTE 1: There are several things being done with the variable fn_new
# NOTE 2: I'm not passing anything back to a.py
```

In b.py, I tried `from a import fn_new`, but it expects fn_new to appear outside of `if __name__ == "__main__":` in a.py. I don't want to move "fn_new" to the main script because I would have to move all of the processing that goes along with it.

How do I access the variable "fn_new" from subprocess.run without importing? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: You cannot pass variables to subprocesses - only their values can be passed in and out. As long as you stay in the same language, you should *import* the other program instead of running it in a subprocess - this allows to access and exchange variables.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, blame that on my wording. All of the results from my searches mentioned passing the variable, so that's the term I used. Thank you for correcting me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly the variable is not going to be called by the same name (fn_new).  You can get it by position
Here is a simple script to get you started.

b.py

---

```
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

---

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much. I see that it returns all of the arguments from the subprocess.run as a list, so I could say `fn_new = sys.argv[1]`.